# Stuck in crashlytics, no verification from firebase on running app

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I want to add crashlytics to my app , i followed google docs but when adding crashlytics the verification to run your app never completes.

The verification 3rd step i really struggle with.[image: steps to follow]

Although fabric Io works, it shows the icon in my app and also i can view errors using fabric.

These are my gradle files

App gradle

```
   uildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.innovate.duplicatefileremoval"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    configurations.all { //fix ClassNotFoundException : OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion "26.+"
                }
            }
        }
    }



    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation project(':sectionedrecyclerview')
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android'
    implementation 'com.tuyenmonkey:mkloader:1.4.0'
    implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

this is project gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        // Add the following repositories:
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        //Crashlytics requires Google Services plugin version 3.1.2 or higher
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
       //  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i have run my app several times still nothing.

Comment: tried crashing no changes

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have to add the debug/release key fingerprints to the console.

Debug is simple to connect, for release you need to switch the build-type once.

It does not need any crashes to confirm the connection.

Comment: @danwalker why you `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` in the dependencies ??

Comment: i added the sha1 key from signing report to console ,after that i ran my app nothing changed.

Comment: i started a new fire base project in console and again link my project with application id and passing SHA1 key fingerprint , this time it worked as it was asking for add fire base and here the key was uninstalling my app and then reinstalling app which added firebase sdk to project and then 2 options appear (whether you have crashing sdk installed i.e fabric or no sdk installed) i already had fabric io so i just had to link fabric with firebase  now i see crashlytics.